# Confused with the proof that the total variation is a positive measure, how to write a double infinite series as one infinite series,

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

I am confused with a step in the proof of Theorem 6.2 in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* which is in page 117.

It claims that $\sum_{i,j}|\mu(A_{ij})|\le|\mu|(E)$ since $A_{ij}$ is a partition of $E$, by the definition of the total variation, which is, $|\mu|(E)=$sup$\sum_i|\mu(E_i)|$ where the supremum is taken over all partitions $E_i$ of $E$, it seems that we should write $\sum_{i,j}|\mu(A_{ij})|$ as an infinite series rather than a double infinite series to get the conclusion. By Cantor's diagonal argument, $\{A_{ij},i,j=1,...\}$ can be written as $\{A_{11},A_{12},A_{21},A_{31},A_{22},A_{13},...\}$, denote it by $\{A_1,A_2,...\}$, is it true that $\sum_{i,j}|\mu(A_{ij})|=\sum_i|\mu(A_i)|$?

Rudin says it uses the Corollary of Theorem 2.17 in the step $\sum_{i,j}|\mu(A_{ij})|\le|\mu|(E)$, which is, $\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}=\sum_j\sum_ia_{ij},a_{ij}\ge0$, it does not make any sense to me, how can that lead to $\sum_{i,j}|\mu(A_{ij})|\le|\mu|(E)$, can anyone explain it to me?

Here are the Theorem 6.2 with its proof: 
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36h1z.png).

Apologize for my poor language, I am not a native speaker.

And this is my first question, appreciate for your help.

UPDATE: Suppose $a_{ij}\ge0,a_{11}+a_{12}+a_{21}+a_{31}+a_{22}+a_{13}+...$ converges. Let $b_k=\sum_{i+j=k}{a_{ij}}$, then $\sum_ib_i=(a_{11})+(a_{12}+a_{21})+(a_{31}+a_{22}+a_{13})=a_{11}+a_{12}+a_{21}+a_{31}+a_{22}+a_{13}+...$ since $a_{11}+a_{12}+a_{21}+a_{31}+a_{22}+a_{13}+...$ is convergent, so my first question can be restated as: is it true that $\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}=\sum_ib_i$?

Comment: related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524613/sum-n-1-infty-b-n-sum-m-1-infty-sum-n-1-infty-a-m-n-sum

Answer (score 2):

Rudin cites the corollary to Theorem 1.27 because *in general* you can't always collapse the double sum $\sum_i \sum_j a_{ij}$ into a single sum $\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}$; the sum may differ depending on whether you sum over $i$ or $j$ first. Also, summing diagonally as you mentioned doesn't always work either, because if $\sum_i \sum_j a_{ij} \neq \sum_j \sum_i a_{ij}$ then the diagonal sequence can be divergent due to oscillation. See for example [page 11 here](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-007-calculus-revisited-multivariable-calculus-fall-2011/study-materials/MITRES_18_007_partV_sol01.pdf).

The point of Theorem 1.27 is that you can always do this when $a_{i,j} \geq 0$ because in that case the sums always coincide. So really when he says:

> Note that the Corollary to Theorem 1.27 is used in (2)

He is "using" the result when he writes $\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}$, because that notation implies that the double sum can be expressed as a "single" sum.

Comment: The point of my problem is that I want to write $\sum_i\sum_j|\mu(A_{ij})|$ as a single infinite series explicitly, $\sum_i|\mu(A_i)|$ is the only one I can figure out, that's why I want to know that whether it is true that $\sum_i\sum_j|\mu(A_{ij})|=\sum_i|\mu(A_i)|$, and actually, the sum of any rearrangement of $\mu(A_i)$ equals to $\sum_i|\mu(A_i)|$ since it is absolutely convergent, thus it suffices to show that $\sum_i\sum_j|\mu(A_{ij})|=\sum_i|\mu(A_i)|$.

Comment: It seems that I figure out a proof of $\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}=\sum_ib_i$(see my UPDATE). I now know that $\sum_i\sum_j|\mu(A_{ij})|$ can be expressed as a single infinite series, but I still don't understand why Rudin cites the Corollary to get the conclusion since $\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}=\sum_j\sum_ia_{ij}$ does not implies that $\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}=\sum_ib_i$ since we can easily construct a counterexample: $\{1,-1,0,0,...;-1,1,0,0,...;0,0,1,-1,0,0,...;0,0,-1,1,0,0,...,...\}$.

Comment: In my first comment, the sum of any rearrangement of $\mu(A_i)$ means the sum of any rearrangement of $|\mu(A_i)|$.

Comment: @DLQian Rudin's theorem is for non-negative sequences, so your counterexample isn't valid. Look at Theorem 1.27 again.

Comment: Yes, I know that, actually, I said I proved  $\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}=\sum_ib_i$ when $a_{ij}\ge0$. My question now is that the Corollary($\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}=\sum_j\sum_ia_{ij}$)does not implies $\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}=\sum_ib_i$ in general since counterexamples exist, actually the proof of $\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}=\sum_ib_i$ depends on the convegence of $\sum_ib_i$ and $a_{ij}\ge0$. So, I think, the Corollary is irrelevant to the conclusion that $\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}=\sum_ib_i$, I don't understand why Rudin cites the Corollary here now, it seems that the conclusion should be proved respectively.